# Specifying type of value without specifying type of key for object

Tags: typescript

I have a rather complex `interface` that will have many well known instances. These instances should be referable by some kind of ID. Ideally I would like to define all of these well known instances in an object so that I can use the `keyof` operator to trivially have a type for the key.

```
interface Complex { 
  frobs: number[];
  type: 'A' | 'B';
} // More complicated in reality

const COMMON = {
  foo: { type: 'A', frobs: [] },           // this is fine
  bar: { type: 'B', frobs: [1], zorg: 1 }, // unwanted extra
  baz: { type: 'A', noFrobs: "uh-oh" },    // frobs missing
}

Type CommonId = keyof typeof COMMON; // Great, valid Ids are "foo" | "bar" | "baz"
```

But if I specify the object without any type (as above), Typescript of course doesn't enforce that all values in that object should be of the same type.

So I wanted to specify that all values must be of type `Complex` but I couldn't do so without specifying the key type. And now I have to mention every key twice: Once as part of the `CommonId` and once in the object:

```
interface Complex { 
  frobs: number[]; 
  type: 'A' | 'B';
} // More complicated in reality
type CommonId = "foo" | "bar";         // Much more common objects in reality

const COMMON: { 
  [commonId in CommonId]: Complex 
} = {
  foo: { type: 'A', frobs: [] },
  bar: { type: 'B', frobs: [1] }
}
```

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds? I would love to just extend the `COMMON` variable with a new key-value pair to automatically add that key to the `CommonId` type.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

As of [Typescript 4.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator), this is now trivially done with the `satisfies` keyword:

```
const COMMON = {
  foo: { type: 'A', frobs: [] },          
  bar: { type: 'B', frobs: [1], zorg: 1 },
                            //  ~~~~~~~ <- ERROR
  baz: { type: 'A', noFrobs: "uh-oh" },
                //  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <- ERROR
} satisfies Record<string, Complex>;

type CommonId = keyof typeof COMMON; // Good, it's still "foo" | "bar" | "baz"
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

This is a further simplified solution (most credit goes to Aplet123 as it's highly inspired by his answer and especially his comments, with only an additional generic function I wrote). My use case was actually defining a config hence the `makeConfig` name.

```
export function makeConfig<C>() {
  return <K extends string>(cfg: Record<K, C>) => cfg;
}
```

If that's useful, you can export and re-use the config function for a common type:

```
interface Complex {
  frobs: number[];
  type: 'A' | 'B';
}

export const complexConfig = makeConfig<Complex>();
```

And then use it simply like this:

```
export const COMMON = complexConfig({
  foo: { type: 'A', frobs: [] },
  bar: { type: 'B', frobs: [1] }
});
```

(Note there's no need for the other variable/type declarations like `CommonId`, unless you want to export them)

Or if you want to use it just once for Complex type:

```
export const COMMON = makeConfig<Complex>()({
  foo: { type: 'A', frobs: [] },
  bar: { type: 'B', frobs: [1] }
});
```

EDIT: or slightly more concise:

```
// generic definition
type ValueTypeCheck<C> = <K extends string>(x: Record<K,C>) => Record<K,C>;

const valueType = <C,>() => (x => x) as ValueTypeCheck<C>;

// usage
const complex = valueType<Complex>();

export const COMMON = complex({...});
```

Overall, we really need a built-in mechanism in TS to enforce the type of values without using an indexed type, which then loses information about the key names...

Answer (score 3):

You can first create a variable without the typing, use that to get the key type, then export the same value but with the types:

```js
interface Complex { frobs: number[]; }

const _common = {
  foo: { frobs: [] },
  bar: { frobs: [1] }
};

type CommonId = keyof typeof _common;

export const COMMON: { 
  [commonId in CommonId]: Complex 
} = _common;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHANhAD2QG9kYp0AjAZwC5kQBXTS6AbQF0BuZAXwCh+CdCGphkAfWGZMI5AF4S-ZGXTp6pclTrJOfADTLklOFA1kKNemwCMHPv15dBYAJ7YUGGSICSAEwVkAGsIV3QYZDcPcMlpWRBnfkJsdChxYVFxVAB5AFlc7IA5cyM2ON8A0DQseP8Oei88QmRHQKkakWcgA)

Comment: Dang, I have chosen a too simple `Complex` type. Your example almost works, but as I have a union type as part of the complex objects I get errors like `type string is not assignable to 'A' | 'B'`

Comment: The `Complex` type shouldn't matter if you're using it as a value. ([see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAGwgDygXigbygMwCc4AjAZwC4oA7AVwRIkIG0BdKAHygCJ845uAbigBfTjwCC3cdwBCQgFAKAxnGplgUAPqqECNVlwKoBflTxFSlKG1EAaY1BIBDQuYLFyVZgEZ2IhRFBJVBIWER9agBJABNDAGsIEDh8KFCIFO1dSOCFdDA4Qk1VdU0YAHkAWUrygDl3R2ZstVioAEtqcL0WmNYqeCRUDEDDHQi1YKA)) I suspect that since your key types are restricted down now, when you try to index into the object with a `string` type then TS will complain due to not being one of the key types.

Comment: This is a link to the code on the Typescript Playground, it sadly doesn't compile:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHANhAD2QG8AoZZGKdAIwGcAuZEAV0xugG0BdAbnORgAntghMA5AEFxyAD7JxAIXH8AvsgD0G5AFl0UFAix5gCOJAAmyUMgNxcwYaWGi0WTOhABJKwF4FMOjoMvLiNHBQKpraOiwIABbIHgbIRpgeIMi0AFYQCGB01pl2Dk6kRiB0YMgA+qgA8jo69QByyP5kFIHoTMSCImIK0gA0lNT0TDzIqsMC4VC9-aISyqNUtIzInACM3NOzqvzlnlVojc0tvQKcaRk+RW7pnj7cTBg4+ARq7bUNTa38IA

Comment: Ah, the error appears to be coming from the fact that your union relies on value types, which typescript does not automatically narrow down values to.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for your input it really got me excited and it is a nice trick. But sadly it doesn't quite fit my scenario.

Comment: [I found a way to make it work.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHANhAD2QG8AoZZGKdAIwGcAuZEAV0xugG0BdAbnORgAntghMA5AEFxyAD7JxAIXH8AvsgD0G5AFl0UFAix5gCOJAAmyUMgNxcwYaVJbbEe7iHIAFogDWXjAsIAhgwOgggr5gyABWLHQxkLi4dIIiEHQIUMDYSejWIDDQyABu9iyZyHBpGDj4BC7aYN4ofhBe2HBQMegwUcBpQSFhEdZpLebWMYnAKcjYBnTQpVUtbR3poqTDoeGRMPpIdXiEADwA0siEkCAWaYk5IADmAHwAFKVMAEoQRlAWS4AGjQxgarwAlD8-vpARcQSdwSQBAYwCwoJFSmpnEYQIlkAB9VAAeR0OmJADlkABeShHCCIwjvMgUQ7oJjELZiBTSEFUWiMZA8ZCqIECGjdDlciTKPnUehMTgARm4ItIqgh-FIwlEoMwmAiAEkrLT2kI+lyLUTSeSKVrcfiSWTKdD-oC6gaQMaEWDCK8aYSnbb+EA)

Answer (score 0):

```js
type ValueTypeCheck<T> = <K extends string>(x: Record<K,T>) => Record<K,T>
const valueType = <T>() => (x => x) as ValueTypeCheck<T>
const complex = valueType<YourObjectValueGoesHere>() // use type of object value

export const validationRules = complex({...}) // replace ... with your object
```